# What is the excel percentrank algorithm in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

[image]

According to the picture, I want to use excel percentrant function in my c# project. what is the solution?

Comment: Please show some code to let us know what is going wrong with what you are trying. If you don't want to implement it youself, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.percentrank(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I donT have any idea so I cannot start writing

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/algorithm-computing-excel-percentrank-t946312.html):

```
private static double PercentRank(List<double> matrix, double value)
{
    matrix.Sort();

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count; i++)
        if (matrix[i] == value)
            return ((double)i) / (matrix.Count - 1);

    // calculate value using linear interpolation
    double x1, x2, y1, y2;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (matrix[i] < value && value < matrix[i + 1])
        {
            x1 = matrix[i];
            x2 = matrix[i + 1];
            y1 = PercentRank(matrix, x1);
            y2 = PercentRank(matrix, x2);

            return (((x2 - value) * y1 + (value - x1) * y2)) / (x2 - x1);
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Out of bounds");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample implementation in JavaScript (matches the results from [Office docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/percentrank-HP005209212.aspx)).

```
function percentrank(x, vec) {
    var s = 0;
    var b = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < vec.length; k++) {
       if (vec[k] < x) {
           s += 1;
       } else {
           b += 1;
       }
    }
    return s/(s+b-1);
}
```

Usage:

> percentrank(2, [13, 12, 11, 8, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1])

Comment: Old thread but I needed this and this answer is incorrect. See sample for value five on Excel doc. =PERCENTRANK(A2:A11,5)

Percent rank of 5 in the range A2:A11. Unlike the examples above, 5 is not found in the range. The PERCENTRANK of 5 is calculated by finding the one-quarter mark between the PERCENTRANK of 4 and the PERCENTRANK of 8. This is (0.555)+(0.25*(0.666-0.555)), or 0.583.

0.583

Answer by @X.L.Ant is the correct one

Answer (score -4):

You can use interOp libraries. But if this is should be used with grate care since if there is a loophole or a memory leakage, it may end up in desater. This is due to you call and create a separate process to do your work. Specially not recommended for ASP.net.

Following is a good article on how to do it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683